# Diferença entre STAThread e MTAThread

Tags: .net, thread

Qual a diferença entre STAThread e MTAThread e quando devo usar uma ou outra?

Porque e como é que dizem apenas respeito ao COM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `MTA` e `STA` são especificações de comportamento para threads de objetos COM. Utilize STA em objetos onde você não pode garantir *thread safety*.

**Versão longa**: Existem duas excelentes respostas no Stack Overflow em inglês. Traduções, e um adendo final, seguem:

> O modelo de *threading* utilizado pelo COM é um modelo de "apartamento"
>   , onde o contexto de execução de objetos COM inicializados está
>   associado com uma única thread (*Single Thread Apartment*) ou várias
>   (*Multi Threaded Apartment*). Neste modelo, um objeto COM, uma vez
>   inicializado em um apartamento, é parte dele pela duração do tempo de
>   execução do mesmo.
>
> O modelo STA é usado para objetos que não são *thread-safe*. Isso
>   significa que eles não lidam com sua própria sincronização - um uso
>   comum é um componente de interface de usuário. Portanto, se outro
>   segmento precisa interagir com o objeto (como apertar um botão em um
>   formulário), a mensagem é empacotada para o segmento STA.
>   O *Windows Forms Message Pumping* é um exemplo disso *[n.t.: uma fila de processamento]*.
>
> Se o objeto COM pode lidar com sua própria sincronização então o
>   modelo MTA pode ser usado onde vários segmentos estão autorizados a
>   interagir com o objeto, sem chamadas controladas.

Joseph Daigle, original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta

Uma outra resposta vai mais além:

> Uma *thread* que cria qualquer janela deve sempre criar um
>   *single-threaded apartment*. Um STA dá garantias de segmentação para
>   qualquer objeto COM que não é *thread-safe*; muito poucos são. A
>   infraestrutura COM assegura que os métodos de tal objeto são sempre
>   chamados a partir da thread correta, enfileirando as chamadas se
>   necessário. Muito semelhante ao `Control.Begin / Invoke()`, mas feito
>   automaticamente, sem qualquer codificação.
>
> Uma série de objetos do Windows contam com essa garantia.
>   Notavelmente as janelas de diálogo (como OpenFileDialog), Clipboard e
>   Drag+Drop não funcionariam corretamente sem essas garantias, e também muitos
>   controles ActiveX (*WebBrowser* sendo um que você é usualmente utilizado
>   em projetos WinForms). Tornar a sua interface em uma *thread* MTA
>   resulta em erros difíceis de diagnosticar - *deadlock* sendo um dos mais
>   comuns. Ou uma exception causada quando o *wrapper* .NET para o
>   componente verifica que ele foi criado em um STA.

Hans Passant, original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192646/when-to-use-mtathread

Ainda, de acordo com a MSDN,

> Um Apartamento é o nome dado aos grupos de processos onde os objetos
>   COM são divididos. Um objeto COM existe em apenas um Apartamento, no
>   sentido que seus métodos podem apenas ser chamados diretamente por uma
>   thread que pertence àquele apartamento.

Original: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693344(v=vs.85).aspx