# MTA Thread Attribute afeta em Thread

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

Suponhamos que eu tenha a classe

```
static class Program{
[MTAThread]
static void Main(string[] args){
Application.Run(new Form());
}
}
```

e simplismente quero aplicar um `Thread.Sleep(1000);` isso mantém o Form estável ou trava a janela igual ao `[STAThread]` num `Thread.Sleep(1000);`.

OBS: Não utilizando o `BackgroundWorker` para aplicar nada.

Ex: Tenho o Visual C# 2008 e quero fazer com que eu tenha um controle de inscritos do meu canal no youtube. E preciso que um `WebBrowser` vá ao endereço `http://youtube.com/user/[MEU_CANAL]/about` e lá pegar o sourceCode da página e executar uma busca pelo elemento que me da essas informações de inscritos e visualizações. E até hoje não encontrei nenhuma ferramenta que possa fazer isso sem que tenha o acesso à página `about` do canal selecionado.

Comment: Esta questão está muito confusa... o que tem a ver `MTAThread` com fazer requisições web?

Comment: É que tipo quando faço uma requisição de Web o aplicativo trava e depois de um longo tempo retorna. Mas é isso que entra o MTAThread. Se o STAThread faz o aplicativo travar quando chama o Thread.Sleep será que o MTAThread atrapalha o Thread.Sleep também?

Comment: Acho que você deve **reformular** a pergunta, pois atualmente está difícil entender aonde você quer chegar. Evite utilizar `MTAThread`, não há motivo para usá-la nesse caso, veja [está pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23782/6454) para mais detalhes. Uma outra coisa, é necessário o `WebBrowser`? não é mais fácil fazer uma requisição e tratar as informações recebidas?

Comment: `MTAThread` e `STAThread` não possuem nenhum tipo de ligação com o `Thread.Sleep`, eles se aplicam apenas a forma como certos objetos COM se comportam em um aplicativo Multi-Threaded e provavelmente não tem nada a ver com o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Vou deixar uma resposta que atende a sua necessidade, mas utilizando outra abordagem. Se a sua necessidade é ler conteúdo HTML de uma página na Web, vai ter muita dificuldade em fazer isso usando o controle WebBroser, principalmente fora de uma aplicação Windows Forms. Eu consegui realizar o que você precisa usando a classe `System.Net.WebClient` e a library **HTML Agility Pack**. Basta trocar o valor da variável `nomeDoCanal` para o canal que deseja ler os dados:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string nomeDoCanal = "FOO";
string source = client.DownloadString(String.Format("https://www.youtube.com/user/{0}/about", nomeDoCanal));

doc.LoadHtml(source);

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul").FirstOrDefault(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("about-stats"));
HtmlNode[] itens = node.Descendants("li").ToArray();
HtmlNode liSubscribers = itens[0];
HtmlNode liViews = itens[1];

string subscribers = liSubscribers.Element("b").InnerText;
string views = liViews.Element("b").InnerText;

Console.WriteLine("Subscribers: {0}", subscribers);
Console.WriteLine("Views: {0}", views);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Para obter a library HTML Agility Pack, utilizando o nuget:

```
PM> install-package htmlagilitypack
```

Se não puder utilizar Nuget, pode baixar uma versão aqui (link Release Binaries):

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/HtmlAgilityPack/1.5.5

> Troque o 1.5.5 pela versão desejada, na própria página do nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/, ao lado direito, existe um link chamado "manual download"

O trecho relevante de HTML da página do Youtube é o seguinte. Tenha em mente que qualquer alteração de layout do Youtube fará esse programa parar de funcionar:

```
<ul class="about-stats">
    <li class="about-stat ">
  <b>312,992</b> subscribers
</li>
    <li class="about-stat ">
  <b>71,629,148</b> views
</li>
```

Link do site da biblioteca:

http://html-agility-pack.net/