# O que é COM (Component Object Model)?

Tags: windows, independente-de-linguagem, interoperabilidade, component

Estava lendo [esta pergunta<sup>1</sup>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23782/18246) aqui no site e me deparei algumas vezes com o termo "objetos COM".

Uma breve pesquisa me mostrou que **COM** quer dizer ***Component Object Model***, mas não consegui extrair mais informações do que isto.

O que eu gostaria de saber é:

- O que é um objeto COM?
- Qual a utilidade disto?
- A relação do COM é apenas com a interface gráfica?

---

<sup>1</sup> [Diferença entre STAThread e MTAThread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23782/18246)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O COM é o .NET antigo :P

Para outra pessoa talvez eu explicasse de outra forma, mas para quem entende porque o .NET existe, é isso. Falo do .NET, da [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) especificamente, não do C#. Mas o COM trabalha com comunicação entre processos.

O COM foi a forma que a Microsoft encontrou para aplicações heterogêneas usando diversas tecnologias possam se comunicar sem muito conhecimento dos detalhes entre elas. A comunicação é feita com contratos fortes na [ABI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187944/101) e em algumas semânticas bem específicas. Ele garante um padrão para a troca de objetos (num sentido geral, não no sentido de OOP, COM não é OOP ainda que dê algumas facilidades para gerenciar objetos desta forma). Ele não é sobre API que é algo específico de cada aplicação/componente.

É uma bela de uma gambiarra, mas na época parecia uma boa ideia. Cumpre seu papel. Até hoje muita coisa no Windows só pode se comunicar através de COM. Mesmo tecnologias mais novas da Microsoft usa COM como base, por exemplo o UWP.

O .NET, claro, se comunica com outros componentes externos a ele através de COM. Nem tudo precisa ser por COM, mas ele tem algumas vantagens já que cria um mínimo denominador comum sem exigir muito dos componentes e aplicações que o estão usando.

.NET conversa bem com tudo que se conforme com ele, mas não com outras tecnologias. O C++ tem um modelo bem interessante pra conversar com componentes escritos em C++, mas não com outras formas. E assim vai com a maioria das linguagens e plataformas. O COM junta tudo isto. Ele não se importa com modelos de memória, com APIs, com organização de código, nada destas coisas. É claro que ele tem uma especificação de como deve ser usado e qualquer tecnologia deve se conformar com ele. Em tese qualquer linguagem pode trabalhar bem com ele, de C à JavaScript (sim o JS acessa COM em certas implementações), passando por Java, C#, C++, Pascal, PHP, Python, etc.

Tem uma série de especificidades que eu acho que não vem ao caso aqui. Ele é bem complicado e chato de lidar.

> A relação do COM é apenas com a interface gráfica?

Vale pra qualquer tecnologia que queria se conformar com ele. Não é exclusivo da Microsoft e menos ainda só de GUI.

## Comparação

Alguns concorrentes dele são: [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), [XPCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPCOM), [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus), etc. Cada um com suas próprias características, vantagens e desvantagens.

Não diretamente, mas dá pra comparar com [REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/101) que é uma forma de aplicações conversarem e trocarem objetos. Obviamente de forma muito diferente pela natureza e objetivos das tecnologias.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: _"...num sentido geral, não no sentido de OOP, COM não é OOP..."_ Discordo. COM **é** OOP, mesmo que dê pra fazer usando línguas não-OOP. Ele suporta os princípios básicos de OOP, como SRP, LSP, inversão de dependência, passagem de mensagens, tudo como manda o figurino.

Comment: @Wtrmute sim, até é mesmo em certo sentido. Mas não da forma geral como as pessoas conhecem OOP. A pessoa pode achar que é uma linguagem OOP.

Comment: É porque as pessoas têm uma ideia torta de que é OOP. Em todo caso, pra COM ser uma linguagem OOP falta só ser uma linguagem. A mesma coisa, claro,  vale pro concorrente do COM, o CORBA.

Comment: Na verdade tem trocentas ideias do que é OOP, e cada um acha que aprendeu é a certa. Eu já até respondi alguma coisa sobre isso. Pra falar de OOP tem que saber o que a pessoa aprendeu que é. E existem "documentos" corroborando a maioria dessas ideias. Como eu não sei qual é a certa eu escolho uma que faz mais sentido pra mim ou que é mais usada e vou nela. As outras eu considero como algo que deveria ter outro nome porque causa confusão com o que é entendido na prática. De fato o COM só falta ser uma linguagem mesmo.